# How can I script Eclipse from another application?

Tags: eclipse, scripting, ocaml

I have an application, written in OCaml. I want that application to script a running instance of Eclipse. How can I do that?

Apparently, there is, or used to be something called Eclipse Monkey that allowed you to script Eclipse from various languages.

One way, I suppose, would be to use an Eclipse plugin to listen on a port and use some protocol for issuing commands to Eclipse. That's ugly, though. Is there a better way?

Comment: (1) Could you be more specific about what you want your OCaml application to access/modify in Eclipse? (2) Is Eclipse Monkey not good for your purposes?

Comment: I want the OCaml code to tell Eclipse to open a file, navigate to a particular line. Eclipse Monkey looks to be dead: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/468810/

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to swap clipboard content with selection upon keyboard shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17298876/how-to-swap-clipboard-content-with-selection-upon-keyboard-shortcut)